# Таймер в android

Tags: java, android, таймер

Я далеко не спец в программировании. Делаю приложение для своих детей. Суть вопроса в следующем. Имеем задание, его надо решить, при выводе Activity с заданием запускается таймер от 0 и до момента решения.

Реализовано таким образом с помощью интернета:

```
public TextView timerValue;
private long startTime = 0L;
private Handler customHandler = new Handler();
long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
long updatedTime = 0L;

private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
    updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;
    int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
    int mins = secs / 60;
    secs = secs % 60;
    int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
    timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":" + String.format("%02d", secs) );
    customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
   }
};
```

И вывожу время в text view text_time

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.universal);
     startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
     customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
     timerValue = findViewById(R.id.text_time);
```

Останавливаю отсчёт при завершении условия в методе if

```
customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
```

Много кода, но всё работает, время тикает и останавливается.

**Вопрос следующий**, по завершении задания, вызываю новое диалоговое окно в котором есть ещё один text view texttimerresult. Так вот вопрос, как туда передать остановленное значение таймера из text_time? Уже мозги закипают, всё перепробовал((( Помогите как это можно реализовать. Спасибо.

Comment: покажите как вы выводите диалог пожалуйста

Comment: dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.previewdialog);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.setCancelable(false);dialog.show();

Comment: по факту ваш вопрос о том, как передать значение из активити в диалог, да? тогда зачем в заголовке речь о таймере, если к вашей действительной проблеме он имеет очень и очень далекое отношение

Comment: Возможно таймер реализован не правильно, что и влечёт за собой ошибку. Возможно с потоками что то не так. Я указал, что новичок в Android studio. Исходя из вышеперечисленного, посчитал более правильным оформить тему таким образом.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева.

Answer (score 0):

Вы устанавливаете в `text_time` этот текст насколько я понял:

```
"" + mins + ":" + String.format("%02d", secs)
```

Я вижу два варианта решения:

1. Делаете глобальную переменную, в которую сетите тот же стринг что и в textView. Дальше при вызове диалога вы берете эту переменную и устанавливаете в `textView` который находится в разметке диалога.
2. Делаете функцию (или она уже у вас есть) которая показывает диалог,и в эту функцию передаете стринг который опять таки дальше устанавливаете в `textView`.

Для того чтобы установить текст в textView разметки диалога, вы объявляете переменную которая будет этим виджетом, а дальше все так же как и в функции `onCreate()`. [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655599/alertdialog-builder-with-custom-layout-and-edittext-cannot-access-view) тут есть дополнительная информация по работе с таким видом диалогов. У вас тоже правильно, но вдруг понадобятся детали :)

### UPDATE

Вы ведь как-то показываете диалог. Значит вам нужно сделать глобальную переменную как вы сделали это например с `startTime`, выглядеть будет так:

```
private String result = "";
```

дальше вы при установке текста в `text_time` присваиваете так же значение и для новой переменной, только в момент когда вы останавливаете таймер. У виджета [textView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView) есть такая функция как `getText()`. У вас будет что-то типа такого:

```
result = timerValue.getText().toString();
```

теперь у вас есть глобальная переменная которая может быть отображена в виджете диалога. Так же можно передавать в функцию которая отображает диалог. Так как я не знаю что и как вы делаете в  программе, то я предположу:

```
void showDialog(String data){
dialog = new Dialog(this); 
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.previewdialog); 
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT)); 
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.show();
}
```

дальше вы берете либо присланную дату, либо глобальную переменную (все зависит от ваших желаний) и устанавливаете текст в textView диалога:

```
resTextView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.your_id)
resTextView.setText(data); // либо если не прислали data то установите result
```

и все. Сейчас проверить не могу, но если что-то не получится то дайте знать.

Comment: Буду пробовать, спасибо.

Comment: и добавьте в ваш вопрос код показа диалога, чтобы всем было удобно :)

Comment: Если не затруднит, подскажите более подробно с синтаксисом, поскольку я только осваиваю Java. Спасибо.

Comment: @user3118150, обновил ответ :)

Comment: Благодарю Вас. Буду пробовать.